# How to run .py scripts from batch files while using anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda

I have several .py scripts which I prepared using python. I used to run those scripts using batch files by simply writing the names of the scripts in .bat file. Recently, I have installed anaconda & deleted other python versions. In anaconda, I am not being able to run the .py scripts from .bat file. When I run the .bat file it says, "Can't find a default Python"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check which python version has been installed with conda `python -V`. Usually it is python 2.7. If so, simply running `python script.py` should suffice.

In case you have other virtual environments/python versions installed, you could check that by running `conda info --envs` (from the [documentation](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/envs.html#list-all-environments)). In that case, you can activate them and run the scripts in the same fashion, `python script.py`.